# Format for a POST JSON Request Body, with nested dictionaries and lists, to API using VBA-Web Library

Tags: vba, ms-access, post

I am trying to format the request body for my POST request to a DHL API. In this request body are nested dictionaries and lists.

I found examples of formatted POST request bodies for the VBA-Web Library, but none have nested dictionaries and lists.
VBA-Web Library: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web
VBA-Web Library Docs: https://vba-tools.github.io/VBA-Web/docs/#/WebRequest/Body

This example also does not show how to implement nested dictionaries or lists:
[Post JSON to web in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021540/post-json-to-web-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Most JSON examples here use VBA-JSON from the same author - eg see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70356847/478884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example using VBA-WEB

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim Body As New Dictionary
    
    Body.Add "key1", 22
    Body.Add "key2", "Hello"
    Body.Add "key3", New Dictionary
    With Body("key3")
        .Add "subKey1", 99
        .Add "subkey2", "World"
        .Add "subkey3", New Collection
        With .Item("subkey3")
            .Add 1
            .Add 2
            .Add 3
        End With
    End With
    
    Debug.Print WebHelpers.ConvertToJson(Body, 2)

End Sub
```

Output:

```txt
{
  "key1": 22,
  "key2": "Hello",
  "key3": {
    "subKey1": 99,
    "subkey2": "World",
    "subkey3": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
}
```